MLKit iOS Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
I add MLkit via cocoapods, but I can't even build the app, even without other MLKit related code.
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:

      -[MLKVisionImage initWithBuffer:] in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

      -[MLKVisionImage initWithMLImage:] in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

  "_CMSampleBufferIsValid", referenced from:

      -[MLKVisionImage initWithBuffer:] in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKITx_FBMLImageInfo", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKTextRecognizer", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in shared.framework.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64


Could you please provide more detailed steps for reproducing this crash? Our QA team did not encounter this issue prior to release, so we are investigating if there are any specific corner cases that may have triggered it. Thank you.

@herz were you able to fix this issue?
